# How to Crop a Zoomin image in Android

Tags: android

In my app,user can select image from gallery and after that he can zoom in/ zoom out that image .

After that user wants to save that zoomin/zoom out image.

I dont want the default android crop method.

How to get the zoomed image's current height & width for cropping.

Anybody have any idea how to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While zooming you should store current zoom level and center of zooming area. With this values you could calculate current height/width as original height/width divided on current zoom level. With this size and coordinates of current image's center you may easily find out the region of image you want to save.